# Do you have more information about the Algerian Yitro feast of boys?

Tags: minhag, food, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, parashas-yisro, parties-celebrations

My father told me the Algerian Jews do a feast similar to the Tunisian's Yitro feast of boys. It happens the same day. This feast is apparently called "Molke Tsion" and is dedicated to the glory of Zion (Sion may here be a deformation of SIOM: Seudat Yitro U Moshe). He also told me there was a tradition to drink a soup for this celebration.

Do you have more information about this Algerian celebration?

When was it created and why?

How do you celebrate it?

Comment: Near the bottom of the following link it mentions the feast, with a source from something called Luach Davar B'ito. Doesn't really give much more information than you have here though... http://www.torah.org/learning/hamaayan/5769/yisro.html#

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.torah.org/learning/hamaayan/5769/yisro.html# (hattip:  @Salmononius2):

> Thursday night of the week of Parashat Yitro: It was the custom among the Jews of Tunis to hold a "Seudat / Feast of Yitro" on this night. Some say that the feast commemorates the feast that Yitro made in this week's parashah (18:12). Others say it celebrates the betrothal of the Jewish People to the Torah (see Rashi to Devarim 33:4). Finally, some say that the occasion is a feast of thanksgiving for the end of a plague that attacked the community's children at an unspecified time in history. (Luach Davar B'ito p.554)
>
> The Jews of Algiers also celebrated this day with a feast, which they
>   called, "The Feast of Siyum"--an acronym in Hebrew for Seudat Yitro
>   v'Moshe. (Luach Davar B'ito p.554)